# How do I add a thumbnail image to my Stellaris mod on the Steam Workshop?

Tags: steam, stellaris, steam-workshop

I have used the Stellaris launcher to add a mod to the Steam workshop for the game of the same name, but after doing so, it appears with a blank thumbnail:

[image]

Going from the steam side of things, you can manually upload an image, but there doesn't seem to be an option to select it as the thumbnail:

[image]

I can't for the life of me seem to find anywhere to actually set the thumbnail. The in-game upload screen seems to be lacking this as well.

[image]

Is this something doable in-game, or is there some workshop setting that I'm missing? ([There definitely *are* mods for this game with thumbnails](http://steamcommunity.com/app/281990/workshop/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure by now you solved this, but I'll leave here my answer for others that may encounter this issue. I had this issue too with my mods https://steamcommunity.com/id/savalina/myworkshopfiles/ and didn't find any help elsewhere, but I sorted it out.

Make sure you add the thumbnail tag `picture="picname.png"` in the `yourmod.mod` file, not in the `descriptor.mod` file located in your mod folder.

Comment: What folder does picname.png go in?

Comment: @AaronFranke It goes in your mod folder.

Comment: For those that say my solution doesn't work: bear in mind that my original answer is from 2016 and it worked at that time (as proved by my own uploaded mods). In the last year Paradox has changed their launcher to v2 and it's completely different (and mods are uploaded from launcher). Also it's possible that Steam made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

The game wiki has a rather detailed guide that explains this too: http://www.stellariswiki.com/Modding#Mod_structure.
There also is a section specific to the Steam Workshop, but is not relevant in this case.

Answer (score -1):

for others who find this make sure its 400 by 400 in pixel size or it wont work